# Multiple choice question about the continuity of sum and product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

Which of the following statements is/are not True below

$A.$ if the sum $f(x)+g(x)$ is a continuous function at $x=a$, then both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are individually continuous at $x=a$

$B.$ if the product $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, then both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are individually continuous at $x=a$

$C.$ if the product $f(x)g(x)$ is a discontinuous function at $x=a$ and $f(x)$ is also discontinuous at $x=a$, then $g(x)$ is a continuous function at $x=a$

$D.$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are discontinuous at $x=a$, then their sum may not be discontinuous at $x=a$

My analysis:

For option $A$ its given that  $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)+g(x)=f(a)+g(a)$$ and by properties of limits

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)+\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=f(a)+g(a)$$ which might also be true if $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)-2$$ and $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=g(a)+2$$

Hence Option $A$ is in general not true .

Similarly for Option $B$ the two individual limits can be

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=\frac{f(a)}{2}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=2g(a)$$

so option $B$ is also not True.

Option $D$ is True since $f(x)=[x]$ and $g(x)=-[x]$ are discontinuous at $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ but their sum $h(x)=0$ is continuous.

Option $C$ is True since when

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) \ne f(a)g(a)$$ and

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)\ne f(a)$$ Then $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=g(a)$$ so $g$ is continuous.

Please correct me whether any corrections are there in my answers.

Comment: Note that C) is false.

Comment: A) Not quite. The limits may not exist, but  your notation assumes that they do.. If $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, then there's no such thing as its limit at $a$. If If $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, then so is $g = -f$; however, $f+g$ **is** continuous at $a$ (right?). Correct that A) is false, though.  Similar comments for the other parts. If you mean to proceed by contradiction then you should say so more explicitly. But A) B) and C) you don't have to: what you need in each case is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ has the counterexample of $f+(-f)$ for any function $f$ that is not continuous at $a$.

$B$ has the counterexample of $g\equiv 0$ for any function $f$ that is not continuous at $a$.

$C$ has the counterexample of $f=g=\chi_{\{0\}}$. Then of course none of $f$, $g$, or $fg$ are continuous at $0$.

$D$ follows from $A$.

Comment: what is $\chi_{0}$

Comment: The characteristic (or indicator) function of $\{0\}$.